# Run appium test on command line

Tags: command-line, testng

Currently I am running Appium tests using Run as -> TESTNG TEST on Eclipse. I want to do the same using command line. Anyone can explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute test using command line, you can use Build tool like Ant or gradle.

Sample testng example using Ant you can find here, https://github.com/amitbhoraniya/TestNG.

You can take reference from here and can create your own task.
Official Documentation of testng ant task you can find here. [TestNg-Ant](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html)

To run tests using gradle, you can find example here
https://github.com/amitbhoraniya/GradleTestNg